# ¿Como separar una variable usando una "," y de esta sacar dos variables?

Tags: c++

Buenas he estado intentado hallar la forma de separar un numero de N cantidad de dígitos luego de una "," he usado el  **cin.ignore** pero este solo me sirve para los primeros dígitos antes de esta , me gustaría saber como poner en otra variable los que estén después de la ",".
mi código:

```
int datos;
 cout<<"ingrese por favor el diámetro del lago en M, e ingrese que tanto se ve el junquillo en el centro del lago en CM , separe los números con una "," "<<endl;
    cin>>datos;
    cin.ignore(10,',');
    cout<<datos<<endl;
```

quiero lograr que al ingresar por ejemplo 2456,342 me guarde en una variable el 2456 y en otra el 342

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa un flujo de datos de texto:

```
std::stringstream valores(datos);
int a, b;
valores >> a;
valores.ignore(1);
valores >> b;

std::cout << a << ' ' << b;
```

Si escribes por consola 2456,342 el código anterior produce la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 2456 342
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HIp3zho1vhsSuKm0).

Comment: hola gracias de antemano , pero he estado intentando usar un espacio en vez de una coma pero no logra reconocer el numero siguiente osea el 342 , no se si sabes por que sucede o como puede arreglarlo.

Comment: No puedo saberlo sin ver tu código @Andrek pero puedo adivinarlo. Has capturado la entrada con `std::cin >> datos;` prueba usar `std::getline(std::cin, datos);`

Answer (score 1):

puedes separar los elementos y añadirlos a un vector, de esta forma puedes acceder a ellos individualmente:

```
vector<string> split(string strToSplit, char delimeter)
{
    stringstream ss(strToSplit);
    string item;
    vector<string> splittedStrings;
    while (getline(ss, item, delimeter))
    {
       splittedStrings.push_back(item);
    }
    return splittedStrings;
}
```

Siendo strToSplit el string que quieres separar y delimeter el elemento que los separe.
No olvides:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
```

No olvides tampoco que para separarlo el elemento tiene que ser un string.

Puedes probarlo en tu main con:

```
int main()
{
    string  test= "2456,342";
    string segment;
    vector<string> seglist = split(test,',');

    for (string n : seglist)
    cout << n << endl;            
}
```

El resultado debería ser:

```
2456
342
```

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo en cuenta que ambas variables son de tipo `int`, recuperar dichos valores es trivial:

```
int var1, var2;
char separador;
std::cin >> var1 >> separador >> var2;

std::cout << var1 << ' ' << var2;
```

Este código funciona porque la sobrecarga del operador `>>` para el tipo `int` deja de leer cuando se encuentra un caracter que no se corresponde con un dígito numérico. Así, leemos el primer número, a continuación leemos el separador y, finalmente, leemos el segundo número.